# how do I change cd /home/ubuntu to use My files / Linux files

Tags: games

im trying to install a .zip game with the linux terminal and in the tutorial im using (https://ubiq.co/tech-blog/install-zip-file-linux/) its example is cd /home/ubuntu/file
mine is My files/LInux files/file [image: the directorys and wanted file] and ive tried cd /My files/ Linux files and it says no file or directory exist how can i fix this and am i being stupid

Comment: What does `ls $HOME` return? You need to quote filenames/directories with spaces, like `cd "/this is a test/of a spaced directory"`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape spaces to let your shell know that it is part of the path, and not a delimiter between arguments as usual.

For escaping characters you can use a backslash `\` in front of the character you want to escape:

`cd ~/My\ Files/Linux\ Files/`

You can also use quotes to escape a whole string:

`cd '~/My Files/Linux Files/'`

or

`cd "~/My Files/Linux Files/"`

The `~/` is a shortcut to your users home directory, which makes it faster than typinh `/home/username/` every time